# named column range vba

Tags: vba, excel

I was wondering if anyone could help. I have the following code below which pulls information based on a specific condition ("Electric") in Column I from the cost report ("i") into the Test sheet ("e"). I would like to avoid using the static reference of column "I" and change it to my named reference "MPT" within the sheet.

```
Public Sub Main() 
Set i = Sheets("Cost Report")
Set e =Sheets ("Test")
Dim d
dim j

d = 1
j=2

Do until IsEmpty(i.Range("I" & j))
IF i.Range("I" & j) = "Electric" Then
d = d+1
e.rows(d).Value-i.Rows(j).Value

End if
j=j+1
Loop
End sub
```

I have tried to insert the code below and replace the reference of column "I" with "IC" but can't get the macro to work.

```
Dim rG As Range
Dim IC AS Long
Set rG=Range("MPT")
IC=rG.Column
Do Until IsEmpty(i.Range("IC" & j))
If i.Range("IC" & j) = "Electric" Then
```

Comment: is the `MPT` range only 1 column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that the `MPT` range only has 1 column. If not, let me know.

In this case, you can qualify the range object and loop through each cell in the range to test the condition.

I also got rid of the `j` counter, because it was superfluous.

```
Public Sub Main() 

Set i = Sheets("Cost Report")
Set e = Sheets("Test")

Dim rG as Range, cG as Range
Set rg = i.Range("MPT")

Dim d as Long
d = 2

For each cG in rG
   If cG.Value2 = "Electric" Then
      e.rows(d).Value-i.Rows(d).Value
      d = d+1
   End if
Loop

End sub
```

Comment: Thanks Scott, could I ask how it would change if the MPT range was more than 1 column?

Comment: @user3792992 - the code would not change necessarily, but you can think about and see how it would affect the execution given your data

Comment: I keep getting an error of 'Loop without do" when I run through the code, I have checked the end if but not sure where the error is.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a sample of one can do it. For more information, you could refer to the following website http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/the-vba-guide-to-named-ranges. Hope it helps.

```
'Single Cell Reference (Worksheet Scope)
  RangeName = "Year"
  CellName = "A2"

  Set cell = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(CellName)
  Worksheets("Sheet1").Names.Add Name:=RangeName, RefersTo:=cell
```

Comment: how does this actually help the OP solve his issue? He doesn't need to know how to name a range in VBA.

Comment: The site that I posted has what he want. I can't possibly copy and paste the whole site for him so yea I am just citing an example from the site for his reference. Hope it helps.